# What does "-->" mean in C?

Tags: c, printf

I have a question, what mean "-->" in C? For example:

```
int a, b, c, x;
a=2001;
b=1000;
c=2;
x=a-b*c;
printf("First: %i", x-->0);
```

It will print "1".
But:

```
printf("Second: %i", x-->0);
```

will print "0". Why when I use it second time, it print "0"?

Answer (score 4):

`x --> 0` is to be read `(x--) > 0`.

Answer (score 3):

`x-->0` is parsed as `(x--) > 0`.